# Link one framework with multiple sub projects in Xcode workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a workspace that contains multiple projects - Project A and Project B. In this case, Project B is a dependency of Project A. When Project A is built, project B is then added as a dynamic framework to Project A.

`- Project A
  - Framework 1
- Project B
  - Framework 1`

Both Project A and Project B rely on a framework (Framework 1). I add this framework to both projects by going `Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths -> Add path to Framework 1`. When I compile the project, I get Xcode warnings saying:

`Class XXX is implemented in both PATH 1 and PATH 2. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

What I really want to do is to tell Xcode to link the Framework with both sub projects but to understand that this is one common library that doesn't need to be duplicated. I have two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If it's not possible, will this warning cause any problems? For example, is it that Xcode will just use the source code from either Framework location or is it that Xcode could run parallel instances of the framework code which could cause issues with singletons being duplicated.